# Different projects on Google App Engine have same dns records

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two projects in Google App Engine, i have my own domains from which i want to access them. I've added the custom domains to each project but found out the dns records that Google App Engine provides are exactly same, thus both my domains which are two different domains( Eg: abc.com, xyz.com ) now connect to the same website.

Answer (score 1):

Technically all GAE apps are mapped from the DNS perspective to the same ingress infrastructure via either `appspot.com` or, for custom domains, `ghs.googlehosted.com`, so it is expected for their IP addresses to fall into a very small range (4 addresses presently).

Serving a particular GAE app is done by extracting the app id from the `appspot. com` subdomain or from the configured custom domain mapping.

If you unexpectedly see a different app and you want help debugging you need to provide details about your app's environment and configuration.

Comment: I accidentally deployed the same apps on both projects, that was causing the issues. Both domains now point to their respective apps. Thank you for your time.